# Safe rule applying remotely using NFT

Tags: linux, firewall, nftables

If you have experience, could you please advise how to safely apply firewall rules remotely on Linux using `nft`?

Particularly on Debian, we used for a long time `iptables-apply(8)` to safely apply remotely firewall rules to avoid lock out ourselves in case of some mistakes in rules.

As of now, latest Debian release comes with `nftables` instead of `iptables`, and official advice is to start using new tool `nft`.
I known that there is wrapper that converts old style `iptables` rules on the fly, but everywhere it advised to not mix old style with new one, so we finally decided to switch all rules to a new (sort of `pf`) style, but we are still humans and don't want to lock ourselves out of remote servers in case of mistake in rules.

So shortly, is there some procedure to do the same as `iptables-apply` but using `nft`?

Comment: This is a cross-post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595273/safe-rule-applying-remotely-using-nft

Comment: @dirdi the cross site post is asked by FossilDaemon, the same user who is asking this question.

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan So it's a deliberate cross-post. [So much the worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310).